# Configure random proxies with R for scraping

Tags: r, http, web-scraping, proxy

I scraped a website authorizing scraping in robots rules but sometimes I get blocked.

While I contacted the admin to understand why, I want to understand how I can use different proxies within R to keep on scraping without being blocked.

I followed this quick tutorial:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy

So I edited the environment file:

```
file.edit('~/.Renviron')
```

and within this I inserted a list of proxies to be selected randomly:

```
proxies_list <- c("128.199.109.241:8080","113.53.230.195:3128","125.141.200.53:80","125.141.200.14:80","128.199.200.112:138","149.56.123.99:3128","128.199.200.112:80","125.141.200.39:80","134.213.29.202:4444")
proxy <-paste0('https://', sample(proxies_list, 1))
https_proxy=proxy
```

But when I scrape with this code:

```
download.file(url_proxy, destfile ='output.html',quiet = TRUE)
html_output <- read_html('output.html')
```

I keep being blocked.

Am I not setting the proxies correctly?

Thanks !
M.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set environment variables, not R variables. See `?download.file` for more details.

eg

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy=proxy)
```

before anything else happens.  Also note the warning in the docs:

```
These environment variables must be set before the download code is
first used: they cannot be altered later by calling 'Sys.setenv'.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Neal Futz. Not sure to understand what the warning means when they mention "cannot be altered later". Practically, does that mean I can use Sys.setenv(http_proxy=proxy) just once in a lifetime?

Comment: I think it means you can set the proxy at any time before the download code gets initialized, but afterwords it's frozen  and won't change (even if you change the env var).

Comment: So not sure how I should do if I want to change the proxy again and then use download.file() after that...

Comment: You could start a new R process.

Comment: method = `wget` or method = `curl` might or might not help.